Checking if a object is visible in any of the viewports
trying to check if a object is visible in any of the viewports, found a tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-remove-item-from-list
copied and pasted his code and passed the reference of the bpy.context.active_object's location instead in my script but its throwing an error?, did they update or brought any changes to this function?, or is it deprecated?, tried checking out the documentation
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html, tried passing the 'default' parameter, no luck
my registered operator code:
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils


class BlenderUnity_ExportFBXInViewport(Operator):
    bl_idname = "blenderunity.fbxinviewportview"
    bl_label = "Export (FBX: In Viewport/View)"
    
    def execute(self, context):
       # get blender unity settings scene
        scene = bpy.data.scenes["blenderunity_settings"]
        
        
       
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                region_3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        origin_2d = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(
                            region,
                            region_3d,
                            bpy.context.active_object.location
                        )
                        
           
           
        return {"FINISHED"}

Error Message: "AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D'object has no attribute 'perspective_matrix'

blender version: 3.6.17

closed and reopened blender and its not throwing that error anymore, my script editor was somewhat bugged it wasn't updating my code when I ran, it ran a previous code, I closed and reopened blender and pasted the same code and it worked
